# Alternative for If-else

Tags: c#, if-statement, foreach

I'm a noob programmer, 1 month into my first class. Right now i'm fooling around making a WINFORM-application in C# that is supposed to some sort of cash register for a bar.

The form consists of:
- 6 buttons named Drank1 to Drank6
- one OK button
- One textbox and button named total.
- a reset-button that accompanies each "drank" button.

The essence of the form is: you type in name, type, content and price in the textboxes and one of the    drankbuttons gets a name & value. after youve named these buttons, you can press them a desirable amount of times then press total to get the price of every drink combined.

The form works as expected but i whas wondering. I wrote a if-else statement connected to the pressing of the OK button that needs to be pressed in order to declare values to the buttons.

I did this with the following piece of code.

```
private void btnValidate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnDrank1.Text == "Drank1")
        {
            btnDrank1.Text = txtNaam.Text + "\n" + txtInhoud.Text + "cl";
            drank[0].Naam = txtNaam.Text;
            drank[0].Inhoud = txtInhoud.Text;
            drank[0].Prijs = Convert.ToDouble(txtPrijs.Text);
        }
        else
        {

            if (btnDrank2.Text == "Drank2")
            {
                btnDrank2.Text = txtNaam.Text + "\n" + txtInhoud.Text + "cl";
                drank[1].Naam = txtNaam.Text;
                drank[1].Inhoud = txtInhoud.Text;
                drank[1].Prijs = Convert.ToDouble(txtPrijs.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                if (btnDrank3.Text == "Drank3")
                {
                    btnDrank3.Text = txtNaam.Text + "\n" + txtInhoud.Text + "cl";
                    drank[2].Naam = txtNaam.Text;
                    drank[2].Inhoud = txtInhoud.Text;
                    drank[2].Prijs = Convert.ToDouble(txtPrijs.Text);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (btnDrank4.Text == "Drank4")
                    {
                        btnDrank4.Text = txtNaam.Text + "\n" + txtInhoud.Text + "cl";
                        drank[3].Naam = txtNaam.Text;
                        drank[3].Inhoud = txtInhoud.Text;
                        drank[3].Prijs = Convert.ToDouble(txtPrijs.Text);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (btnDrank5.Text == "Drank5")
                        {
                            btnDrank5.Text = txtNaam.Text + "\n" + txtInhoud.Text + "cl";
                            drank[4].Naam = txtNaam.Text;
                            drank[4].Inhoud = txtInhoud.Text;
                            drank[4].Prijs = Convert.ToDouble(txtPrijs.Text);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (btnDrank6.Text == "Drank6")
                            {
                                btnDrank6.Text = txtNaam.Text + "\n" + txtInhoud.Text + "cl";
                                drank[5].Naam = txtNaam.Text;
                                drank[5].Inhoud = txtInhoud.Text;
                                drank[5].Prijs = Convert.ToDouble(txtPrijs.Text);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("6 dranken is genoeg!", "My Application",
                                MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                            }
```

I was wondering if there is a way to reduce the amount of code and still get the same result. I was thinking maybe a foreach loop, but can't quite figure out how exactly to write one with custom classes.

Cheers

Comment: `else if ( condition ) { statements }`

Comment: You could chain this all together using `else if`.

Comment: Else if would work but a switch would be a lot better.

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning that all that code is duplicated anyway. If you can get the index of the drink your selecting instead of the text (or just parse the int out) you can bring that down to just the 4 lines you duplicate in every statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is called a switch statement.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-switch

It would end up looking something like this:

```
switch (btnDrank2.Text)
{
    case "Drank2":
        btnDrank2.Text = txtNaam.Text + "\n" + txtInhoud.Text + "cl";
        drank[1].Naam = txtNaam.Text;
        drank[1].Inhoud = txtInhoud.Text;
        drank[1].Prijs = Convert.ToDouble(txtPrijs.Text);
    break;

    case "Drank3":
        btnDrank3.Text = txtNaam.Text + "\n" + txtInhoud.Text + "cl";
        drank[2].Naam = txtNaam.Text;
        drank[2].Inhoud = txtInhoud.Text;
        drank[2].Prijs = Convert.ToDouble(txtPrijs.Text);
    break;
}
```

etc. The code may have errors as I do not have access to a c# compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Use the switch statement. in you case the code would be something like that

```
private void btnValidate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string text = btnDrank4.Text;
     switch(text)
     {
           case "Drank1":
              btnDrank1.Text = txtNaam.Text + "\n" + txtInhoud.Text + "cl";
              drank[0].Naam = txtNaam.Text;
              drank[0].Inhoud = txtInhoud.Text;
              drank[0].Prijs = Convert.ToDouble(txtPrijs.Text);
           break;
           case "Drank2":
           // your code here
           break;

           // here the other cases

           default ""
           // here everything is not the previous values
           // I suppose these lines

           MessageBox.Show("6 dranken is genoeg!", "My Application",
           MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
           break;
     }
}
```